# Why not every [x,y] coordinate on the Secp256k1 curve corresponds to a valid uncompressed publicKey?

Tags: public-key, secp256k1

First, some background.

**1**. There are some coordinates `x,y` satisfying `y^2(mod p)=x^3+7(mod p)` on the Secp256k1 curve that *do not* correspond to a valid Bitcoin **uncompressed** publicKey of the form `04[x,y]`.

We can prove **1** using the `random_point()` function in Sage with unknown generator under`E=EllipticCurve(GF(modi), [0,7])`. If we get *lucky*, after a few trials Sage returns a point such as Q.

```
   Q=E.random_point()

   Q
   (B8F0170E293FCC9291BEE2665E9CA9B25D3B11810ED68D9EA0CB440D7064E4DA : 
    691AA44502212591132AA6F27582B78F9976998DE355C4EE5960DB05AC0A2A3 : 1)
```

Now we have:

```
   Qx=B8F0170E293FCC9291BEE2665E9CA9B25D3B11810ED68D9EA0CB440D7064E4DA
   Qy=691AA44502212591132AA6F27582B78F9976998DE355C4EE5960DB05AC0A2A3
```

We verify that `Qy^2(mod p) = Qx^3+7 (mod p)` is satisfied so we confirm that Q is a point on the Secp256k1 curve.

Next, we try to validate Q as an **uncompressed** Bitcoin publicKey:

```
04B8F0170E293FCC9291BEE2665E9CA9B25D3B11810ED68D9EA0CB440D7064E4DA691AA44502212591132AA6F27582B78F9976998DE355C4EE5960DB05AC0A2A3
```

We get: `Q is not a valid publicKey`.

Yet, checking the validity of the *mirrored* point -Q, returns a valid publicKey:

```
   -Qx=B8F0170E293FCC9291BEE2665E9CA9B25D3B11810ED68D9EA0CB440D7064E4DA
   -Qy=F96E55BBAFDDEDA6EECD5590D8A7D4870668966721CAA3B11A69F24EA53F598C
```

Valid publicKey for -Q:

```
04B8F0170E293FCC9291BEE2665E9CA9B25D3B11810ED68D9EA0CB440D7064E4DAF96E55BBAFDDEDA6EECD5590D8A7D4870668966721CAA3B11A69F24EA53F598C
```

Valid publicKey for -Q (hashed):

`1A2gaiiKy91Pmx8EUcbT4Hd6JFZ3sQvUhM`

Question:

Why not every [x,y] coordinate on the Secp256k1 curve corresponds to a valid **uncompressed** publicKey?

**Note:**

In this question, by *validity* I mean a set of EC coordinates (x,y) that can be hashed into a bitcoin **uncompressed** address. I am specifying **uncompressed** for obvious reasons. My question is detailed enough I hope to show that it's not referring to compressed Bitcoin addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are valid public keys just that in the first case the uncompressed public key is not represented in a valid hexadecimal format. If you look closely, your `Qy` has 63 hexadecimal digits (so there is a 'half-byte'). Although hashing can be done in bit boundaries, most standard implementations out there do not support it.  Just try to concatenate '0' at the start of the Qy to get `Qy = 0691AA44502212591132AA6F27582B78F9976998DE355C4EE5960DB05AC0A2A3` so that you get a full byte. So now your uncompressed public key is `04B8F0170E293FCC9291BEE2665E9CA9B25D3B11810ED68D9EA0CB440D7064E4DA0691AA44502212591132AA6F27582B78F9976998DE355C4EE5960DB05AC0A2A3`, which would hash to P2PKH address: `17Y1XJiC72f2kyJnzwBdkaPQEGgaD1aroR`

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for your prompt answer.